# React and redux webpack config error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm pretty new in this. I trying to learn react/redux and i have an error in my code.

The error is on the commented line, exactly the first dot:

```
const userReducer = (state={}, actions) => {

    if(actions.type == 'name')
    {
        state.name = actions.value;
    }else if(actions.type == 'age')
    {
        state.age = actions.value;
    }
    //const newstate = {...state};
    return state;
};
```

If i remove the comment, i get this error by webpack-dev-server:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:19)

  11 |      state.age = actions.value;
  12 |  }
> 13 |  const newstate = {...state};
```

My webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool : 'inline-source-map',
    entry : [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    out : {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve : {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_module/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins : [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

How can i fix this error? If i well informed, three dots are in ES6 and i can use the ES6 anonymous function syntax without error. What do i miss?

I just copied the config file, i think the problem is there. I installed stage-0 preset with npm, someone who had the same problem it fixed for him.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "treeview",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "treeview",
  "main": "javascript/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
```

Comment: Object spread (`{...state}`) is `stage-2` at the moment (https://github.com/tc39/proposals), so you need to add the `stage-2` to your config.

Comment: Please, could you write it how i can do it exactly? Or better, how can i use the latest stage that includes everything(if i get it right).

Comment: "how i can do it exactly" --- the same way you use `react` and `es2015` presets. "Or better, how can i use the latest stage that includes everything" --- that's not the best idea. Only include what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object spread used in the

```
const newstate = {...state};
```

statement is not standardised yet.

And as of today it's a part of `stage-2` (see https://github.com/tc39/proposals)

So, for it to work you need to plug the `stage-2` preset.

Alternatively you might have used `Object.assign()` that is a part of the ES2015 already:

```
const newstate = Object.assign({}, state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @zerkms say: Object spread ({...state}) is stage-2 at the moment ([github.com/tc39/proposals](http://github.com/tc39/proposals)), so you need to add the stage-2 to your config.

### Solution:

You have to include the stage-2 in your dev dependencies

```
npm install -dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

Then include in your web pack config

```
...
loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-2']
...
```